# A theory of everything?

Tags: metaphilosophy

Did anybody ever try to develop a theory of everything?
By this I mean a single theory which aims to  describe all things in a unified way.
I am not talking on a physical theory of everything, I mean a theory which includes also non physical things, all abstracts concepts?

Comment: Given that you don't want a physical theory which would predict things, what do you want such a theory to *do*? I mean (teasing, but sincerely) here's a theory describing  everything: "Everything is material, including abstract concepts." So what, if anything, does that not do for you? There are different senses in which philosophers from Thales to Plato to Spinoza to German Idealists to contemporary metaphysicians have offered ways of understanding what everything is, but it's hard to tell what you'd want from such a theory.

Comment: Thank you for your theory of everything, do  you plan to define material and abstract in your theory or do you take them as primitive notions? Could you also name the theories of everything of the authors you mention. Thanks.

Comment: A book that deals with this, I think, is Siders "Writing the Book of the World". You can check out the introduction and, more importantly, the table of contents [here](http://tedsider.org/books/wbotw_sample.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

**Yes**

The total number of humans that have graced this earth: roughly 100 billion

The total number of attempts at a theory of everything: probably 500-1000 billion.

I would argue that every individual has tried and failed several times, because it is human nature.

Consider what the purpose of a "theory of everything" is.  Most definitions of "theory" imply that it must be testable -- thus a theory of everything must be testable by future tests.  Since it's a theory of everything, it must predict all future events.

Now at some point, most individuals contemplate the eternal.  Religion spends a great time pontificating on the eternal... its a popular topic.  To contemplate the eternal and one's life in one gulp calls for a theory of everything.  This is pretty darn important if you want to make sure you pick the right religion!

Of course, so far either 100% of these theories have been wrong, or all but one have been wrong (depending on whether you believe your current religion's theory is right or not).  We don't give up; we pick our selves up and try it again!

I would feel comfortable with the claim that every individual has gone through 5 or 6 "theories of everything" before they finish puberty, simply relying on anecdotal evidence.

The tricky bit, of course, is that some of these theories look less like what you might expect a "theory of everything" to look like.  Many of them include things like "God knows all" or "What goes around comes around."  These are fuzzy phrases, but they are not any less a "theory of everything" than the infamous Grand Unified Theory of physics would be.

In fact, there are three famous "theories of everything" which you may be familiar with:

- Physicalism - Everything obeys "natural laws."
- Idealism - Everything is a mind with "freewill."
- Dualism - Some things are physical, others are minds

One could easily argue these are theories of everything, though one is a little pressed for details.  All of them certainly have predictive capacity.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, many times: Bible, Plato's theory of Forms, etc., etc., etc…

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @iphigenie, of course it does. The theories I mentioned, as well as many others, aim to describe everything, both physical and abstract, in a unified way: God created Heavens and Earth and laid down moral codes; or abstract Forms projected into physical world; etc. Practically every philosopher who worked in metaphysics laid down a "theory of everything" that the original poster asked about.

Comment: "As well as many others" is not an answer. This could have easily fitted in a comment. Answers are supposed to be more elaborate than that. Also, the bible is not a theory, while the question was "Did anybody ever try to develop a theory of everything?".

Comment: Besides what iphigenie says, you seem to be confusing Platon's _ideas_ and Aristotle's _forms_.